# How to show the Image Title Tooltip on Click?

Tags: views, media

I have a carousel-view with some Images in it. Each Image Field has Alt and Title attribute. When i am hovering over the images, the title tooltip appears. Thats what i want. Additionally i want to be able to click on the image to get the same result. I guess the solution would be in Javascript, but how do i trigger the same default Behaviour like on Mouseover with a click?

Comment: Use <img src="#" data-original-title="title name" data-toggle="tooltip">

Comment: use two separate js functions, one mouseover function, the other click function.